# equivalent to hwclock in Solaris?

Tags: unix, solaris

Hi all is there an equivalent in Solaris 10 (i86) for hwclock?

I'd like to read the bios time on a machine without rebooting and checking manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Solaris the hardware and system clock are in sync and are both set to UTC (~GMT). You can use the "date -u" command to display that clock.